# Image sizes looking different when resizing browser

Tags: image, browser, resize

Can someone help me understand why some image heights look different in my navbar and do not line up with the others when you resize a browser to certain sizes?

www.wsgdev.com/fsr/test.html

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the aspect ratios of the images do not always match the aspect ration of the table cells. For example, when the Lodging cell is 70x33, the image is also 70x33. But when the Gallery cell is 70x33, the image is 70x32.

There are several other, possibly better, ways to make a navbar. If you prefer this method, you can use cells and images with identical aspect ratios.